# Cannot restart haproxy

Tags: restart, haproxy

I am trying to restart haproxy, when I type

```
      haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

I get the following error:

```
 [ALERT] 212/124840 (9060) : Starting proxy mysql-cluster: cannot bind socket
```

If I type

```
 /etc/init.d/haproxy restart
```

nothing happens.

Comment: If you edit ENABLED=1 in vim /etc/default/haproxy, /etc/init.d/haproxy restart will work, but I get                    * Restarting haproxy haproxy                                                                                  [ALERT] 212/144232 (19089) : Starting proxy mysql-cluster: cannot bind socket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

You aren't running as root; probably needs a sudo in front of your command to start it on the command line if you aren't running as root (check with whoami).
Another process, likely another instance of HAProxy, is already bound to those ports. Check with netstat -apn.

Answer (score 0):

Many a times starting HAProxy service gives error for like

HAProxy cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:port]

For resolving this issue check for another process, likely another instance of HAProxy, is already bound to those ports. Check with netstat -apn.

Kill the other instance of HAProxy.

If this didn't resolve your problem or there is no other process running. You may run the following command. This is resolve the issue.

setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any=1